# Debian boot freeze (hard lockup)

Tags: debian, kernel

I'm using debian sid and during two years i watch the same problem. When I boot from grub my system on the screen appears follow text:

```
Linux kernel in decompress level...Parsing elf
```

and then freeze for 2-3 minutes. In dmesg I looking next messages:

```
    [    1.238499] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.238584] rtc_cmos 00:03: RTC can wake from S4
[    1.238690] rtc_cmos 00:03: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
[   10.291725] ------------[ cut here ]------------
[   10.291729] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 1 at /build/linux-l03Lbg/linux-3.16.7-ckt4/kernel/watchdog.c:265 watchdog_overflow_callback+0xac/0xd0()
[   10.291731] Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 0
[   10.291732] Modules linked in:

[   10.291736] CPU: 0 PID: 1 Comm: swapper/0 Not tainted 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 Debian 3.16.7-ckt4-1
[   10.291738] Hardware name: ASUSTeK Computer Inc.         K52N/K52N, BIOS K52N.213 08/21/2010
[   10.291740]  c1554ccc f5007d74 c1475ef8 f5007d84 c1056ac4 c1554ca4 f5007da0 00000001
[   10.291744]  c1554ccc 00000109 c10dcfdc c10dcfdc 00000009 c10dcf30 f75bf220 f50d7800
[   10.291748]  f5007d8c c1056b13 00000009 f5007d84 c1554ca4 f5007da0 f5007da4 c10dcfdc
[   10.291751] Call Trace:
[   10.291756]  [<c1475ef8>] ? dump_stack+0x3e/0x4e
[   10.291760]  [<c1056ac4>] ? warn_slowpath_common+0x84/0xa0
[   10.291762]  [<c10dcfdc>] ? watchdog_overflow_callback+0xac/0xd0
[   10.291765]  [<c10dcfdc>] ? watchdog_overflow_callback+0xac/0xd0
[   10.291768]  [<c10dcf30>] ? restart_watchdog_hrtimer+0x50/0x50
[   10.291770]  [<c1056b13>] ? warn_slowpath_fmt+0x33/0x40
[   10.291773]  [<c10dcfdc>] ? watchdog_overflow_callback+0xac/0xd0
.................................................................
[   10.291917]  [<c147ad41>] ? ret_from_kernel_thread+0x21/0x30
[   10.291919]  [<c146ff60>] ? rest_init+0x70/0x70
[   10.291925] ---[ end trace 309079724ee3132c ]---
[  149.889649] hpet1: lost 117511467 rtc interrupts
[  149.890104] rtc_cmos 00:03: alarms up to one month, y3k, 114 bytes nvram, hpet irqs
[  149.890122] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[  149.890467] TCP: cubic registered
[  149.890483] NET: Registered protocol family 10
[  149.890677] mip6: Mobile IPv6
[  149.890680] NET: Registered protocol family 17
```

of course, kernels were different (3.2~3.16) but all from debian repository.
another feature — if I reboot notebook (asus x52n), with a probability of 100% it boot without hardlock, quickly. 
any suggestions?

same problem here http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=117192 (160 sec wait and normal boot)

a couple of years ago I installed Debian stable, it does not have this problem. but there is a testing and for sid.

Comment: Out of curiosity. Is your BIOS battery drained?

Comment: Sounds like a BIOS bug, something's not initialized correctly. Any BIOS update available for the system?

Comment: with battery all good.

Comment: No updates to the BIOS. the same problem here: http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=117192